# When running tests with Pytest is there a flag which will show a countdown of tests not yet ran?

Tags: pytest

To elaborate,

platform linux -- Python 3.6.3, pytest-3.2.3, py-1.4.34, pluggy-0.4.0 -- /root/Python-3.6.3/python
cachedir: .cache
rootdir: X
Automation/Orders-Testing, inifile:
plugins: allure-adaptor-1.7.8
collecting ... collected 539 items

Above I have 539 tests. As these tests are executed I would like to know the remaining number. 538, 537, 536 etc to be print out to the command line.

Comment: The latest pytests (3.3) shows a progress bar... also you can get something like that with the plugin pytest-sugar. Is that not enough info for you?

Comment: We use Jenkins so it shows a "estimated" progress bar based on previous runs. I haven't heard of the sugar plug in. I will investigate that.

Comment: Pytest 3.3 does exactly what I needed. We have updated now. Thank you